# How to write a recursive function to populate a tree with nodes that have values computed from their parent node's value?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, function, recursion, tree

I'm new to graph and trees as well as recursion and I seem to have hit a roadblock. I'm trying to code a recursive algorithm to populate a tree. The algorithm is meant to do roughly the following:

- Check currenNode's value (a number).
- Add child Nodes for all possible lower numbers (so if the parent had a value of 3, it would add 3 child Nodes, one with value = 0, one with value = 1, and one with value = 2. It does so in a random order.
- Repeat previous step for all children and their children and their children's children's etc...
- Leaf (terminal) Node's are the ones with value = 0.

The code I have come up with so far is creating the first level of children and goes all the way down to the leaf Node of the first branch of the Tree. I just can't figure out how to make it do the same for all other children.

I can't figure out a way to code it so that when it does the recursive call `populateTree(currentNode.child[0]);` it changes the child index in order to go thru all the children. Can anyone show me how to do this?

```js
var Node = function(value, parent) {
  this.value = value;
  this.parent = parent;
  this.child = [];
};

var Tree = function(value) {
  this._head = new Node(value);
};

var Node = function(value, parent) {
  this.value = value;
  this.parent = parent;
  this.child = [];
};

var Tree = function(value) {
  this._head = new Node(value);
};

var populateTree = function(currentNode) {
  if (currentNode.value === 0) {
    return;
  }
  // Create an array of all possible values lower than currentNode's
  var possible = [];
  for (var i = currentNode.value - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    possible.push(i);
  }

  // Create one child Node for each element in possible array, in random order
  while (possible.length) {
    var val = possible.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length),
      1)[0];
    currentNode.child.push(new Node(val, currentNode));
  }

  // Recursive call I need help with
  populateTree(currentNode.child[0]);

};

tree = new Tree(5);
populateTree(tree._head);
console.log(tree);
```

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < currentNode.child.length; i++) {populateTree(currentNode.child[i]);}`

Comment: please add some ascii graph/image how the tree should look like after inserting a value.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp That's pretty much what I was trying and I couldn't seem to make it work. I must have been doing something different than you because I tried it again using your code and now it works exactly as intended. Thanks.